# Jigsaw cannot create a modular JAR with the jar tool

Tags: java-platform-module-system

I am using the build 9-ea+129-jigsaw-nightly-h5332-20160730

I have a very simple module with a Main class and a module-info.java

I compile the module using javac --module-source-path and everything is ok. The class files are being generated for both module-info.class and Main.class

```
javac -d modules --module-source-path src $(find . -name "*.java")
```

When I try to create the modular JAR file with the jar tool, I get the following error message:

```
module-info.class found in a versioned directory without module-info.class in the root
```

My module-info.class is there in the root directory.

I run:

```
$ jar --create --file mlib/ModuleFirst@1.0.jar --module-version 1.0 --main-class com.firstmodule.Main -c modules/com.firstmodule
```

Can you tell me why do I get this error and what I did wrong?

Thank you

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem

You should change a lot your command

```
$ jar --create --file mlib/ModuleFirst@1.0.jar --module-version 1.0 --main-class com.firstmodule.Main -C modules/com.firstmodule .
```

You must use the capital C and put the dot at the end of line